# sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, httpurlconnection

i am using selenium library for testing purpose. But the following code giving me class cast exception. i have googled this exception but didn't get the solution. i am confused in Https connetion and http connetion. help me to solve this exception. thank you

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection;


public class TestMakeMySushi {

  private static final String HttpURLConnection = null;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dev-24\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.makemysushi.com/404?");

    List<WebElement> linklist = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    linklist.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));
    System.out.println("size of all link and images list" + linklist.size());
    List<WebElement> activelist = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

    for (int i = 0; i < linklist.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
        if (linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href") != null && (!linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href").contains("javascript"))) {
            activelist.add(linklist.get(i));
        }
    }


    System.out.println("size of activelink list" + activelist.size());


    for (int j = 0; j < activelist.size(); j++) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(activelist.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        String response = connection.getResponseMessage();
        connection.disconnect();
        System.out.println(activelist.get(j).getAttribute("href") + "----" + response);
    }
}
}
```

**Exception that i am facing**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
at TestMakeMySushi.main(TestMakeMySushi.java:76)
C:\Users\Dev-24\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@KarolDowbecki's analysis was in the right direction.

Instead of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection;` **HttpURLConnection** should be resolved through:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

I was able to execute your program which produces the following output:

```
size of all link and images list81
https://makemysushi.com/404#navigation
https://makemysushi.com/
https://makemysushi.com/
https://makemysushi.com/sushi-university
https://makemysushi.com/sushi-recipes
https://makemysushi.com/sushi-essentials
https://makemysushi.com/store
https://www.facebook.com/Makemysushi/
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/makemysushi/
https://plus.google.com/+Makemysushi
mailto:info@makemysushi.com   // <-- this href attribute is of MailToURLConnection type raising the java.lang.ClassCastException which can't be casted to HttpURLConnection type
.
.
.
https://makemysushi.com/Sushi-share/contact-us
https://makemysushi.com/Sushi-share/about-us
null
null
null
null
size of activelink list77
https://makemysushi.com/404#navigation----Not Found
https://makemysushi.com/----OK
https://makemysushi.com/----OK
https://makemysushi.com/sushi-university----OK
https://makemysushi.com/sushi-recipes----OK
https://makemysushi.com/sushi-essentials----OK
https://makemysushi.com/store----OK
https://www.facebook.com/Makemysushi/----OK
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/makemysushi/----OK
https://plus.google.com/+Makemysushi----OK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.mailto.MailToURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection
    at demo.TestMakeMySushi.main(TestMakeMySushi.java:48)
```

### Reason

The *List* **activelist** contains an element:

```
<a href="mailto:info@makemysushi.com" target="_blank"><i id="social-em" class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
```

When you are trying to establish a connection through the *href* attribute **mailto:info@makemysushi.com** as in:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(activelist.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
```

A successful connection cannot be established as **MailToURLConnection** object can't be casted to **HttpURLConnection** object and raises **java.lang.ClassCastException**

Answer (score 4):

Change your import statement for `HttpURLConnection` class from `import sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection;` to `import java.net.HttpURLConnection;`.

You are not supposed to use `sun` packages and classes in your application code. They are internal to JVM.

Comment: still getting the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.mailto.MailToURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection
 at TestMakeMySushi.main(TestMakeMySushi.java:57)

Comment: `MailToURLConnection` is not a `HttpURLConnection`, it's a `java.net.URLConnection`. Pay attention to class hierarchy, you can't side step it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue because i imported

**import com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;**

remove that and import below

**import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;**